# tooltip display outside of page not working properly.?

Tags: bootstrap-4, tooltip

use tool tip of button but display in left side of page.
code of :-

```
<div class="pbutton"><a class="pr" data-animation="false" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Product" href="#"></a></div>
```

display screenshot[image]

Answer (score 0):

with tooltips you need to add data-placement="top, bottom, left or right" next to  data-toggle="tooltip"

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Tooltip on top">
  Tooltip on top
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="right" title="Tooltip on right">
  Tooltip on right
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="bottom" title="Tooltip on bottom">
  Tooltip on bottom
</button>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Tooltip on left">
  Tooltip on left
</button>
```

Comment: but it not button is <a>link for popup video

Comment: <a href="#" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="left" title="Hooray!">Product</a>